# How to generate "highlighted country" maps

Tags: openstreetmap

How can I generate a map like this using OSM? I want the map to highlight single country and fade others. Also, if the country is small I want to show it on the globe in a small thumbnail.

[image]

Comment: Whats the reason why you want to use OSM for doing this ?

Comment: @Manuel, no reasons, I just need a way to create a map like this. I thought OSM can do that, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No OSM is just a basemap including a volunteered database and not a mapping library (like a wiki for geographic data)...
Should it be the same mapprojection (Lambert's Conformal Conic Projection) as in the exmaple above, or could it be a simple Mercator-Projection like google maps? Projections: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/ba569633d51ebec6ec6e/. Mercator would be the easiest. 
And are you interested in implementing this server side with a mapserver or the faster approach with a simple library ? Should it be a zoomable "slippy map" or a static interactive map ?
What language ?

Comment: Well, I just want a map "like this", you made me realize how small I know about maps and all that stuff :( The projection: I need one that looks most intuitive and recognizable to most of the people. I guess, it is Mercator projection. Implementation: I need the simplest approach. Library - JVM, Python, JS - is OK. API (like OSM or Google Maps) is OK too. Sorry, but I do not understand what is a mapserver, but I'm not implementing one, definitely. Format: static map, PNG, no zoom and popups. Language: english and russian, but extra languages is plus. Thanks for your attention to this question.

Comment: What I'm doing is a flashcard deck for children. I want to generate maps of different counties (actually, all the countries + oceans + biggest seas, lakes and rivers + mountains), so they can learn geography. I know about Anki's "Ultimate Geograpy" deck, but: 1) It doesn't have consistent map style, 2) It's English only, and sometimes it's hard to guess the correct pronunciation on other languages 3) It is not invented by me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oke let’s using JavaScript, because I think there is the biggest variety of libraries. Here I will explain a few approaches creating an interactive webmap.

**1)**  The first approach is using plain svg:

You can download or draw with your vector software of choice the base map as svg. Then you could assign every country polygon a unique ID, and inside JS you can access the SVG with a mouseevent like click or mouseover. All the information of the country could be stored outside JS in a .json (easier) or .xml file. With the ID you getting from the SVG event you can get the fitting information from your .json. Maybe that reinvent the wheel, but it’s highly adjustable. But I think if you only want a static maps its simpler if you are using a more complex library.

**2)**  The second approach is using a library for svg interaction:

The very popular [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) or [Raphael.js](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/)

**3)**  The third approach is using a thematic webmapping library based on svg:

Use [JQVMAP](https://jqvmap.com/) (former vectormap.js) or the very new austrian project [mapmap.js](https://github.com/floledermann/mapmap-examples)

**4)**  Use a topographic webmapping library

Here you can use the open libraries leaflet.js or openlayers.js. With these, the best approach will be, that you add your countries as a .geojson. Geojson is a very nice format that allows you interacting with your countries with the most geographical softwares.

**5)**  Create und use your own tiles

This approach is the most performant solution but not the simplest to implement.
[Here](http://build-failed.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-2-tilemill.html) is a very nice tutorial explaining five approaches. But I think the simplest is using TileMill.

**6)**  Using a mapserver
If you are not familiar with mapservers, this should only be considered when you are going to implement an extensive application. Nice Mapservers are [Deegree](http://www.deegree.org/) and the popular [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/).

All of these approaches have their pros und cons but I think one of these solutions will fit your needs and I wish you the best successes!

Comment: So many possibilities. Ok then, looks like I need a few nights to grasp them. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oke if you have further question belonging to your chosen approach, it will be a pleasure to ask it in a new post !

Answer (score 2):

You can use google Geo Chart. You can highlight any country you wanted.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geomap'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

      function drawMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};
        options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

        var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);

        geomap.draw(data, options);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more info here is the link 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap?csw=1